# Max path sum in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Consider the following question:

> Given a 2D array of unsigned integers and a maximum length *n*, find a *path* in that matrix that is not longer than *n* and which maximises the sum. The output should consist of both the path and the sum.

A *path* consists of neighbouring integers that are either all in the same row, or in the same column, or down a diagonal in the down-right direction.

For example, consider the following matrix and a given path length limit of `3`:

```
 1  2  3  4  5    
 2  1  2  2  1   
 3  4  5* 6  5    
 3  3  5 10* 5    
 1  2  5  7 15*
```

The most optimal path would be `5 + 10 + 15` (nodes are marked with `*`).

Now, upon seeing this problem, immediately a Dynamic Programming solution seems to be most appropriate here, given this problem's similarity to other problems like [Min Cost Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361555/minimum-cost-path-in-matrix) or [Maximum Sum Rectangular Submatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643908/5459839). The issue is that in order to correctly solve this problem, you need to start building up the paths from every integer (node) in the matrix and not just start the path from the top left and end on the bottom right.

I was initially thinking of an approach similar to that of the solution for [Maximum Sum Rectangular Submatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643908/5459839) in which I could store each possible path from every node (with path length less than *n*, only going right/down), but the only way I can envision that approach is by making recursive calls for down and right from each node which would seem to defeat the purpose of DP. Also, I need to be able to store the max path.

Another possible solution I was thinking about was somehow adapting a longest path search and running it from each int in the graph where each int is like an edge weight.

**What would be the most efficient way to find the max path?**

Comment: Can you explain the example? 10 and 15 are not neighbours, so how can  `10 + 15` be in a path? Also, you say the path can be from *any int to any other int*, so which are those ints in your example -- are they given, or should they be part of the output? Are those ints given by value, or by (row,column) indexes?

Comment: You write *"by going down or to the right"* but present a solution that has a diagonal step. So do you mean *"by going down, or to the right, or diagonal down-right"*?

Comment: Can the matrix have negative numbers?

Comment: @trincot Yes I meant by going down, or to the right, or diagonal down-right and also, the matrix can't have negative numbers

Comment: @trincot Actually, it appears I misread the problem. The constraints are that the path can only be choosing ints in the same row, the same column, or down a diagonal.

Comment: Ah, so the path cannot make "turns", it has to keep going in the same direction?

Comment: @trincot Yes, it that appears to be the case based on what I'm seeing in the description of the question. With this change, I'm not really sure how to go about approaching the solution since the approach for the min path cost problem includes paths that can zigzag. Would your solution work for these new constraints?

Comment: I will post an answer later -- in the mean time I removed my previous answer.

Comment: Are both types of diagonals allowed, or only diagonals which go downwards from left to right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138369/discussion-between-loremipsum1771-and-trincot).

Comment: I updated my answer completely in light of the new requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge here is to avoid to sum the same nodes more than once. For that you could apply the following algorithm:

#### Algorithm

1. For each of the 3 directions (down, down+right, right) perform steps 2 and 3:
2. Determine the number of lines that exist in this direction. For the downward direction, this is the number of columns. For the rightward direction, this is the number of rows. For the diagonal direction, this is the number of diagonal lines, i.e. the sum of the number of rows and columns minus 1, as depicted by the red lines below:

[image]

3. For each line do:

   - Determine the first node on that line (call it the "head"), and also set the "tail" to that same node. These two references refer to the end points of the "current" path. Also set both the sum and path-length to zero.
   - For each head node on the current line perform the following bullet points:

     - Add the head node's value to the sum and increase the path length
     - If the path length is larger than the allowed maximum, subtract the tail's value from the sum, and set the tail to the node that follows it on the current line
     - Whenever the sum is greater than the greatest sum found so far, remember it together with the path's location.
     - Set the head to the node that follows it on the current line

At the end return the greatest sum and the path that generated this sum.

#### Code

Here is an implementation in basic JavaScript:

```js
function maxPathSum(matrix, maxLen) {
    var row, rows, col, cols, line, lines, dir, dirs, len,
        headRow, headCol, tailRow, tailCol, sum, maxSum;

    rows = matrix.length;
    cols = matrix[0].length;
    maxSum = -1;
    dirs = 3; // Number of directions that paths can follow
    if (maxLen == 1 || cols == 1) 
        dirs = 1; // Only need to check downward directions

    for (dir = 1; dir <= 3; dir++) {
        // Number of lines in this direction to try paths on
        lines = [cols, rows, rows + cols - 1][dir-1];
        for (line = 0; line < lines; line++) {
            sum = 0;
            len = 0;
            // Set starting point depending on the direction
            headRow = [0, line, line >= rows ? 0 : line][dir-1];
            headCol = [line, 0, line >= rows ? line - rows : 0][dir-1];
            tailRow = headRow;
            tailCol = headCol;
            // Traverse this line
            while (headRow < rows && headCol < cols) {
                // Lengthen the path at the head
                sum += matrix[headRow][headCol];
                len++;
                if (len > maxLen) {
                    // Shorten the path at the tail
                    sum -= matrix[tailRow][tailCol];
                    tailRow += dir % 2;
                    tailCol += dir >> 1;
                }
                if (sum > maxSum) {
                    // Found a better path
                    maxSum = sum;
                    path = '(' + tailRow + ',' + tailCol + ') - ' 
                         + '(' + headRow + ',' + headCol + ')';
                }
                headRow += dir % 2;
                headCol += dir >> 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // Return the maximum sum and the string representation of
    // the path that has this sum
    return { maxSum, path };
} 

// Sample input
var matrix = [
    [1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
    [2,  1,  2,  2,  1],
    [3,  4,  5,  5,  5],
    [3,  3,  5, 10,  5],
    [1,  2,  5,  5, 15],
];

var best = maxPathSum(matrix, 3);

console.log(best);
```

#### Some details about the code

1. Be aware that row/column indexes start at 0.
2. The way the head and tail coordinates are incremented is based on the binary representation of the *dir* variable: it takes these three values (binary notation): 01, 10, 11

   You can then take the first bit to indicate whether the next step in the direction is on the next column (1) or not (0), and the second bit to indicate whether it is on the next row (1) or not (0). You can depict it like this, where 00 represents the "current" node:

   ```
   00 10
   01 11
   ```

   So we have this meaning to the values of *dir*:

   - 01: walk along the column
   - 10: walk along the row
   - 11: walk diagonally

   The code uses `>>1` for extracting the first bit, and  `% 2` for extracting the last bit. That operation will result in a 0 or 1 in both cases, and is the value that needs to be added to either the column or the row.
3. The following expression creates a 1D array and takes one of its values on-the-fly:

   ```
   headRow = [0, line, line >= rows ? 0 : line][dir-1];
   ```

   It is short for:

   ```
   switch (dir) {
   case 1:
       headRow = 0;
       break;
   case 2:
       headRow = line;
       break;
   case 3:
       if (line >= rows) 
           headRow = 0
       else 
           headRow = line;
       break;  
   }
   ```

#### Time and space complexity

The head will visit each node exactly once per direction. The tail will visit fewer nodes. The number of directions is constant, and the max path length value does not influence the number of head visits, so the time complexity is:

*Θ(rows * columns)*

There are no additional arrays used in this algorithm, just a few primitive variables. So the additional space complexity is:

*Θ(1)*

which both are the best you could hope for.

#### Is it Dynamic Programming?

In a DP solution you would typically use some kind of tabulation or memoization, possibly in the form of a matrix, where each sub-result found for a particular node is input for determining the result for neighbouring nodes.

Such solutions could need *Θ(rows*columns)* extra space. But this problem can be solved without such (extensive) space usage. When looking at one *line* at a time (a row, a column or a diagonal), the algorithm has some similarities with Kadane's algorithm:

One difference is that here the choice to extend or shorten the path/subarray is not dependent on the matrix data itself, but on the given maximum length. This is also related to the fact that here all values are guaranteed to be non-negative, while Kadane's algorithm is suitable for signed numbers.

Just like with Kadane's algorithm the best solution so far is maintained in a separate variable.

Another difference is that here we need to look in three directions. But that just means repeating the same algorithm in those three directions, while carrying over the best solution found so far.

This is a very basic use of Dynamic Programming, since you don't need the tabulation or memoization techniques here. We only keep the best results in the variables *sum* and *maxSum*. That cannot be viewed as tabluation or memoization, which typically keep track of several competing results that must be compared at some time. See [this interesting answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185005/5459839).

Comment: Thanks for the verbose answer! +1 for the illustration and code. One thing I don't understand though is what lines like this are doing: `lines = [cols, rows, rows + cols - 1][dir-1]` It seems like you are initializing a 2D matrix in such lines, but `lines` is later being used like a number instead of a collection. Is this the case?

Comment: The first pair of square brackets creates a 1D array, and the second pair takes an element from that array, so it is like a condensed `switch` statement for assigning a value to `lines` depending on the value of `dir`. It could also have been written with two ternary operators.

Comment: It looks like the solution works, but would it still be considered Dynamic Programming. I'm not seeing any table being built or memoization being used. Is the DP part of it coming just from the fact that we are remember the path with the largest sum? And I'm assuming that the lengthening and shortening of the current path is essentially mimicking the functionality of Kadane's algorithm?

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! Lastly, I noticed that you're keeping track of the beginning and end of each line with the 'head' and 'tail' variables and are updating them like so: `tailRow += dir % 2;  tailCol += dir >> 1; headRow += dir % 2; headCol += dir >> 1;` I've been stepping through the code in my debugger but haven't been able to figure out how they are generating the correct indices. Its like magic! XD The way I would think to iterate through the diagonals at least, is by doing something like [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-matrix-diagonally).

Comment: I added an explanation of this in the middle of my answer, under the header "Some details about the code", point 2.

Comment: Oh ok, it all makes sense now. That's a clever solution, how did you know to do that?

Comment: I don't know, ... I guess after 30+ years of programming, one builds up some kind of intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Use F[i][j][k] as the max path sum where the path has length k and ends at position (i, j).

F[i][j][k] can be computed from F[i-1][j][k-1] and F[i][j-1][k-1].

The answer would be the maximum value of F.

To retrieve the max path, use another table G[i][j][k] to store the last step of F[i][j][k], i.e. it comes from (i-1,j) or (i,j-1).

Answer (score 1):

> The constraints are that the path can only be created by going down or to the right in the matrix.

Solution complexity **O(N * M * L)** where:

- N: number of rows
- M: number of columns
- L: max length of the path

  ```
  int solve(int x, int y, int l) { 
    if(x > N || y > M) { return -INF; } 
    if(l == 1) {matrix[x][y];}
    if(dp[x][y][l] != -INF) {return dp[x][y][l];} // if cached before, return the answer 
    int option1 = solve(x+1, y, l-1); // take a step down 
    int option2 = solve(x, y+1, l-1); // take a step right 
    maxPath [x][n][l] = (option1 > option2 ) ? DOWN : RIGHT; // to trace the path 
    return dp[x][y][l] = max(option1, option2) + matrix[x][y];
  }
  ```

example: solve(3,3,3): max path sum starting from (3,3) with length 3 ( 2 steps)