# sum max path of matrix using dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a matrix `mat[][]`, of dimensions N * N, I need to find the path from the top-left cell (0, 0) to the bottom-right cell (N – 1, N – 1) of the given matrix such that sum of the elements in the path is maximum but I also need to add to sum of the path the maximum element of the path (so I calculate the max value in each path twice). The only moves allowed from any cell (i, j) of the matrix are (i + 1, j) or (i, j + 1)

I need the solution in dynamic programming by using 2 arrays of size (N*N)
with time complexity O(N^2)

Here is a solution that I tried but it's not O(N^2)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MatrixPaths {

    public static List<List<Integer>> generatePaths(int[][] matrix) {
        List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        dfs(0, 0, matrix, new ArrayList<>(), allPaths);
        return allPaths;
    }

    private static void dfs(int i, int j, int[][] matrix, List<Integer> currentPath, List<List<Integer>> allPaths) {
        int n = matrix.length;

        // Add the current cell to the current path
        currentPath.add(matrix[i][j]);

        // Check if we have reached the bottom-right cell
        if (i == n - 1 && j == n - 1) {
            allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(currentPath));
        } else {
            // Move down
            if (i + 1 < n) {
                dfs(i + 1, j, matrix, currentPath, allPaths);
            }

            // Move right
            if (j + 1 < n) {
                dfs(i, j + 1, matrix, currentPath, allPaths);
            }
        }

        // Remove the last element to backtrack
        currentPath.remove(currentPath.size() - 1);
    }
    
    public static int maxSV(int A[][]) {
        List<List<Integer>> allPaths = generatePaths(A);
        int maxSum = 0;
        for (List<Integer> path : allPaths) {
            int sum = 0;
            int maxElement = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // Initialize maxElement to the smallest possible value
            for (int element : path) {
                sum += element;

                // Update maxElement if the current element is greater
                maxElement = Math.max(maxElement, element);
            }
            sum += maxElement;
            // Update maxSum if the current sum is greater
            maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, sum);
        }
        return maxSum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 8, 9}
        };
        System.out.println(maxSV(matrix));
    }
}
```

This returns 38 because the max sum of path is 1->4->7->8->9->9 we added 9 twice because in every path, we take the max element twice.

Comment: This is a well known problem. Did you try Googling for **java matrix find max path sum** ? Maybe these two other SO questions can help: [Max path sum in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851922/max-path-sum-in-a-2d-array) and [Java - Maximum sum in path through a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621337/java-maximum-sum-in-path-through-a-2d-array)

Comment: i know , but in each path we need to count the max element twice , there is differnce
in those examples you gave the return value is 29 but i need to return 38 read my question one more time

Comment: You could speed this up by computing the longest path that goes through each element aij, with the requirement that no element on the path exceeds aij, which is straightforward to implement. To each such path one would compute the shortest path from [0,0] to [i,j] and the shortest path from [i,j] to [n-1,n-1], then sum the two lengths. The idea is that a longest path will go though some [i,j] and aij will be the largest value on that path...

Comment: ...Of course, for many [i,j] it would be determined pretty quickly that there is no such path having the required properties. Even so, the algorithm is not close to O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Store maximums for the best paths (not for all possible paths) in corresponding cells of auxiliary matrix and update them when the best path to this cell is calculated.

Changed to apply max element in the path instantly

```
public class Main {

    public static int maxSV(int A[][], int n) {
        int MaxEl[][] = new int[n][n];
        int MaxSum[][] = new int[n][n];
        MaxSum[0][0]=2*A[0][0];
        MaxEl[0][0]=A[0][0];
        for(int j = 1; j<n;j++) {
            MaxEl[0][j] = Math.max(MaxEl[0][j-1], A[0][j]);
            MaxSum[0][j] = MaxSum[0][j-1]+A[0][j] + MaxEl[0][j] - MaxEl[0][j-1] ;
            MaxEl[j][0] = Math.max(MaxEl[j-1][0], A[j][0]);
            MaxSum[j][0] = MaxSum[j-1][0]+A[j][0]  + MaxEl[j][0] - MaxEl[j-1][0] ;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<n;i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<n; j++) {
                int MaxUp = Math.max(MaxEl[i-1][j], A[i][j]);
                int MaxLeft = Math.max(MaxEl[i][j-1], A[i][j]);
                int SumUp = MaxSum[i-1][j] + MaxUp - MaxEl[i-1][j] + A[i][j];
                int SumLeft = MaxSum[i][j-1] + MaxLeft - MaxEl[i][j-1] + A[i][j];
            
                if (SumUp >= SumLeft) {
                        MaxSum[i][j] = SumUp;
                        MaxEl[i][j] = MaxUp;
                }
                else {
                        MaxSum[i][j] = SumLeft;
                        MaxEl[i][j] = MaxLeft;
                }
            }   
        }
        return MaxSum[n-1][n-1];
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {3, 5, 4},
                {2, 6, 3},
                {8, 4, 5}
        };
        System.out.println(maxSV(matrix, 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this give the optimum if the array were `[[0,2,0], [1,2,2], [4,0,0]]`? The longest path is seen to be `[0,0]->[0,1]->[1,1]->[1,2]->[2,2]`. It has a length of `6` which becomes `8` after its largest element, `2` is added. However, the path `[0,0]->[1,0]->[2,0]->[2,1]->[2,2]` has a length of only `5`, but that becomes `9` after its largest element, `4`, is added. The latter is therefore seen to be the optimal path.

Comment: @Abra, you're right: I was drafting the above comment in an answer box, but then mindlessly published the answer rather than copying the content to its intended destination. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @bara Is my answer still unclear?